# Form data not storing in database

Tags: php

Ok  my registration form data is not getting stored in database. Whereas if i do `$name="Bill";` then its storing but `$name='name';` is not working. Secondly when `i click` on `register button` its shows php code of file `connect.php.`

**Registration code**

```
<body>

<div id="registration">
 <h2><b><i>Electronic Montessori Learning</i><b></h2>

 <form id="RegisterUserForm" action="connect.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
         <p>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="text" value="" />
         </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" class="text" type="password" />
         </p>
       <p>
            <button id="registerNew" type="submit">Register</button>
         </p>
    </fieldset>

 </form>
</div>
<body>
```

and now **connect.php** code

```
<?php


$db=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
mysql_select_db("users") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to Database";


if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
// Storing form values into PHP variables
$name = $_POST['name']; // Since method=”post” in the form
$password = $_POST['password'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_eml(Name, Password) VALUES('$name', '$password' ) ") 
or die(mysql_error());  
echo "Data Inserted!";

echo    'Thank you for submitting your details!';
}




?>
```

Comment: Then your server is not configured with PHP.

Comment: **Careful!** The `mysql_*` functions are [old and should not be used anymore](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). Please have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli), which are better [MySQL API choices](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated code. please use `PDO` or `mysqli_*`.

Comment: You just have got the typical case of SQL injection. Also typically this happens while you start to use mysql with the mysql_* functions. Whoever guided you there, stop now and take a better tutorial. - Your problems are already part of your earlier questioon BTW: [Unable to connect php and html file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060553/unable-to-connect-php-and-html-file)

Answer (score 5):

you forgot `name` attribute here

```
<button id="registerNew" type="submit" name="Submit">Register</button>
```

and because of that this condition will never true

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
  if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
```

is wrong as in the form there is no element with name="Submit".

It means your button should have a name = "Submit".